Continuous function with an open set of solutions
Is it possible to have a continuous function from reals to reals with $f(x)=0$ if and only if $x>0$ or any other open set of values? I'm trying a function question and this is a counterexample that I am trying to fix. One 'example' I thought of was $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x<0$, but then I don't know what value to assign $f(0)$. In other words, how can I find a continuous function where the solution to $f(x)=a$ is an open set for some constant $a$.
Edit: I think I solved my original problem. I can assume that $f(0)=c\neq0$ and so $f(0)-f(x)=c\neq0$ for all $x>0$, which contradicts continuity. Would this be correct?

If $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous and satisfies $f(x)=0$ for $x>0$ then continuity demands that also $f(0)=0$:
We have $\frac 1n\to 0$ for $n\to \infty$, $\frac 1n>0$ for $n\geq 1$ and therefore
$$
f(0)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \underbrace{f\left(\frac 1n\right)}_{=\, 0}=0.
$$

More generally: If $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, $a\in \mathbb R$ and the set
$$
U:=f^{-1}(\lbrace a\rbrace)=\lbrace x\in \mathbb R\mid f(x)=a\rbrace
$$
is open, then either $U=\emptyset$ or $U=\mathbb R$. This is because $U$ is always a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ (with the usual topology) is connected.
